# Start Eclipse on MacOS from Java Command line

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm working with an older version of Eclipse, Helios SR1.

I need to be able to start eclipse from the terminal.

In review of http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

I execute the following command in Terminal to start eclipse.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

and I get

> Root exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/swt/SWTError

So this appears to be more complex than what was found in the above link.  If I double-click the Eclipse.app it starts right up.

I'm wondering what else needs to be done to allow the Command Line Eclipse Launcher to work properly

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to use the `open` command:

```
open /path/to/eclipse.app
```

or

```
open -n /path/to/eclipse.app
```

will open a new instance of Eclipse even if one is already running.

If you must use the Java command you need to specify `-XstartOnFirstThread` before the `-jar` option:

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar ...
```

Comment: That's not what I need to do.  I need to start eclipse via the 'java' command.  I don't understand why people put answers that clearly do not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the eclipse launcher binary:

```
<Your-Install-Path>/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

Default start-up options are set in eclipse.ini:

```
<Your-Install-Path>/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

Kepler start-up options are documented here: https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html (Helios link redirects to Kepler, the oldest one they have kept available)

The launching process is explained in detail here: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html